# How to read custom Http Headers with HttpClient?

Tags: angular

I've got an Http Response with a custom header being returned `x-total-count`. Chrome dev-tools shows that the header is being returned, but when I try to read the header in Angular it's not being parsed.

DevTools output:
[image]

Angular Code:

```
return this.http.post<FileInfo[]>(url.toString(), [], { observe: 'response' })
    .map(response => {
        console.log(response.headers.has('x-total-count'));
        const resp = {fileInfos: response.body, resultCount: Number(response.headers.get('x-total-count'))};
        return resp;
    })
    .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => Observable.throw(error.error));
```

The `console.log` above is returning `false`.

Do I have to do something additional to read custom headers like this?

For reference here are the imports I'm using:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: You'll need to change the backend to add `x-total-count` to your `access-control-expose-headers` header

Comment: Do you want [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: @user184994 That did the trick. Thanks! But if the problem was on the backend, then how did Chrome DevTools see the header?

Comment: The header is always sent, so it's always visible in dev tools, but Chrome (and other browsers) will only allow you to read it programmaticly if that expose header is set